# symfony 4.1 Unable to generate a URL

Tags: controller, routes, symfony4

in my synfony app I have two controllers:
The ActionController is supposed to simply render a template containing a form. Submitting the form, I want to send a GET request to the SpreadSheetControllers getSpreadSheet() method.

This is the ActionController:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class ActionController extends AbstractController {

  /**
   * @Route("/action")
   */
  public function action() {

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('/spreadSheet'))
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Action'))
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('action.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));

  }

}
```

And here is the SpreadSheetController:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class SpreadSheetController extends AbstractController {

  /**
   * @Route("/spreadSheet")
   */
  public function getSpreadSheet() {
    return new Response(
        '<html><body>spreadSheet</body></html>'
    );
  }

}
```

Still, when browsing http://localhost:8000/action I get a RouteNotFoundException:
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/spreadSheet" as such route does not exist.

Does anybody know why the route isn't found??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the *name* of the route, not the actual url. Name your route like so:

```
/**
 * @Route("/spreadSheet", name="spreadsheet")
 */
```

Then reference that name in your ActionController:

```
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('spreadsheet'))
```

Comment: Happy to help @Kevin!